Shortening multi-word proper nouns to one word, kept capitalized
I was reading the Wikipedia article for Joe Arridy and near the bottom it mentions an organization called "Friends of Joe Arridy", and then instead of restating the entire proper noun, it's shortened to "Friends":

A group of supporters formed the non-profit Friends of Joe Arridy and worked to bring new recognition to the injustice of his case


Attorney David A. Martinez became involved and relied on Robert Perske's book about Arridy's case, as well as other materials compiled by the Friends

Is this a stylistic choice or the correct way to shorten multi-word proper nouns to one word? I'd never seen this before.

Surely you've seen this before. People living near New York City, call it "the City", with a capital. In Massachusetts, Cape Cod is often called "the Cape", with a capital.

It's not the only way of doing it, if that's what you mean by "correct". You can define an abbreviation e.g. FJA and some organisations will specify abbreviations or other standard shortenings. Friends of the Earth is normally shortened to FoE not "Friends", but that's an informal standard or convention specific to them. Just do what seems natural and clear.

@PeterShor maybe "the city" or "the cape" but not "the City" or "the Cape".

Does this answer your question? When is correct to capitalise these words? ('... if you were to use the word as a proper name, or as an abbreviated version of a proper name. For example, you would use capital letters to name the Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development; after spelling it out in full the first time, you might shorten the name to "Organisation" on subsequent mentions: "The Organisation is expected to release its study next month." '
[phenry])

@gator - Whyever not, when it refers to a particular city or cape? The City of London is known as 'The City'.

@gator:  Take a look at this webforum.
